# Angular - Query Param with + symbol - send as encoded %2B

Tags: angular, urlencode

I am trying to send a date in the URL with a plus (+) symbol.
The problem is that the + symbol gets replaced with a space.

When I try encoding my date, like so:

`let enforcement_date = this.parserFormatter.format(this.updateDate) + 'T00:00:00.000' + encodeURIComponent('+0000')`

It looks like it gets encoded twice, so this is what I end up with:

`url?&enforcement_date=2019-05-15T00:00:00.000%252B0000`

So the `%2B` comes from the `+`, which is what I want, but it looks like the `%` symbol is also getting encoded with `%25`, which I do not want.

I know they replaced the plus with a space " " in Angular 5.2.7+, but I want to encode my `+` with `%2B` so that my URL looks like this:

`url?&enforcement_date=2019-05-15T00:00:00.000%2B0000`

I don't want to use an interceptor because I don't want to affect other routes.

Any advice?

EDIT:

Okay so this is what I am currently doing:

**Component:**

```
const req = {
  'version': this.version,
  'enforcement_date': this.parserFormatter.format(this.updateDate) + 'T00:00:00.000' + encodeURIComponent('+0000')
}

this.service.update(this.itemToUpdate, req).subscribe(
  (res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
    this.toastr.success('Success')
  },
  (res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    this.toastr.error(res.message);
  }
);
```

**Service:**

```
update(itemToUpdate:string, req:any): Observable<HttpResponse<response>> {
  return this.http
  .put<response>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${itemToUpdate}/firmware/version`, null, {
    params: req,
    observe: 'response'
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] so that we can try it ?

Comment: @trichetriche is that what you wanted?

Comment: I meant something on https://stackblitz.com, which is easier to play with !

Comment: Seems like [a known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18261) anyway